# Docker Compose MariaDB with Adminer

Tags: docker-compose

I was trying to use adminer as my gui to manage my database. For that, in my docker-compose file I defined a Username, a Password and the Database. But everytime I tried to access the database with the correct data. I got the following error:

[image: adminer Screenshot]

And my docker-compose code is the following:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: adminer
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: adminer
      MYSQL_DATABASE: noinch
    ports:
      - 5555:3306
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    container_name: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7777:8080
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must tell the Adminer the environment variables.

```
environment:
   ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: mariadb
```

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: adminer
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: adminer
      MYSQL_DATABASE: noinch
    ports:
      - 5555:3306
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    container_name: adminer
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 7777:8080
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that the env var is necessary only if the database service is called something other than the default `db`.